# Reading of ammeter

Tags: current, current-measurement, multimeter

In my university, we are using these ammeters to measure current:

[image]

What do  the top series of numbers show (0-0.6/1.2), and what do the bottom series of numbers show (0-3/6)?

Comment: Do you understand the concept of a meter having different ranges?

Comment: They all show amps; they are the four scales associated with the measurement range you set at the top with the rotary switch.

Comment: Aside:  When you try to read it, use the mirror behind the needle to line up your eye.  You want to position yourself such that you can't see the needles reflection.  Otherwise you'll get parallax errors.   And the screw at the bottom is how you 'zero' it (if the needle isn't pointing exactly at 'zero' when there's nothing connected)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whichever setting you turn the knob to, the maximum reading is that many amps. If you set the knob to 0.6 then read the top scale. If you set the knob to 3 then read the bottom scale. If you set the knob to 1.2 then read the top scale but double the value you read (if the needle points at 0.4 then the current is 0.8A), and if you set the knob to 6 then read the bottom scale and double the value you read.

For best accuracy, use the smallest scale that contains the value you want to measure.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fudtLa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An ammeter is just a very sensitive voltage meter with a high current shunt resistor across it. This one detects 90 mV full scale. My old Standard analog meter was called 50k Ohms per volt but actually 200 mV full scale. Some were 20kohms/volt or 500 mV FS.

Normally we like to derate max power on resistors to reduce absolute max temp rise by 50% ( typ 125'C max) but you can compute the power in these shunt resistors and estimate their power rating inside.

When designing such current sensors in future **50 mV is a common standard** to keep power at a minimum for 1/4 W R's but if this interferes with performance, much lower values are used or if there is much tolerance then much higher max shunt voltage are used for low currents.